# MPAndroid chart didn't draw linechart points

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, linechart, mpandroidchart

LineChart got smaller and even not visible when entries are above 50. It draws normally with 50 size of entries but with 51, 52 ... n it disappeared.

Here is the example with 52 size of entries.
[image]

Is there any option or argument to fix this issue?

Here are the example of code how I give the data to LineData:

```
val dataSet =
        LineDataSet(
            getChartsEntries(
                context = chart.context
            ),
            "label"
        ).apply {
            setDrawCircles(false)
            setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false)
            setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator(false)
            setDrawFilled(true)
            fillDrawable =
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(chart.context, R.drawable.bg_gradient_chart)
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(chart.context, R.color.blue)
            mode =
                LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER
        }
    val lineData = LineData(dataSet).apply {
        setDrawValues(true)
        isHighlightEnabled = true
        setValueTextColor(R.color.blue)
        setValueTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD)
        setValueTextSize(0f)
    }
    chart.data = lineData
    chart.invalidate()




fun getChartEntires(context: Context) : List<Entry> {
    // Here I just get  Entry(0f, float_value), ... Entry(51f, float_value),
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code? Also, have you looked at the internals of MPAndroidChart, maybe there is a bug there or a hint why it is not drawing 51+ items.

Comment: Ok I can share. Yeah I was looking for everywhere, but nothing found about the limit of this size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case there was an issue when I gave the specific `width` of the chart. I actually had rendered chart with `AndroidView` and had given him `Modifier.requiredWidth = ENTRIES_SIZE * 70.dp`. But when I changed it to dynamically and didn't give him exact width it started work. Instead, I give my chart scrollable property.